# Interactive rebase: modify a recent commit among a bunch of --no-ff merges

Tags: git, merge, git-rebase, git-flow

### The goal

I want to modify a recent commit, using rebase. The magic command is [`git rebase -i`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Let's say you're trying to **delete** the commit-in-question

> - First, find out how far back that commit is (approximately). Then do:
>
>   - **git rebase -i HEAD~10**

-*Source*:
[Greg Hewgill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1338758/1421642) to a less complicated git question

### The problem

That works wonderfully, **unless** you've recently done any --no-ff merges

If you happen to follow [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model), you do --no-ff merges all the time

> - Check the "Sources" section below for examples on the **how** & **why** of rebase -i blowing up --no-ff merges
> - For now, just trust me (or try it yourself): It aint pretty

### The actual question

If we look at [this page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) we see a `--preserve-merges` (or simply `-p`) option that we can try replacing `-i` with

The problem is, if we do that, we're no longer given that nice `-i` pop-up from before
-> The one with choices for "edit this commit, sqaush that one", etc.
--> And so, we can't meet our original goal: modify/delete some recent commit using rebase :(

*So, what do we do?*

---

### Sources

Problem section:

> - [First example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221624/how-to-avoid-git-rebase-killing-merge-commits) of rebase murdering --no-ff commits
> - [Second example](http://notes.envato.com/developers/rebasing-merge-commits-in-git)
>
>   - His quote: "The TL;DR version is this: **When rebasing, always use the -p flag**"

Answer (score 1):

`-p` and `-i` are not mutually exclusive - you can use both at the same time. *However* be very very careful when you do this - changing the order of commits is a *bad* idea. You should also not try to remove merge commits this way; it's very easy to get things into an improper state.

```
git rebase -p -i HEAD~10
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. I believe I was scared to try because of [this page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) saying: "combining [-p] with the --interactive option explicitly is generally not a good idea unless you know what you are doing". It looks like you've covered the "know what you're doing" part for me tho :) So I can use both, just **no reordering** and **no deleting merge commit rows**, and I'm safe?

Comment: I'm not going to blanket say that you're safe, but if you're only editing commits, you'll probably be okay.

Comment: Hrm, gotcha. And the "generally not a good idea" thing is a pretty scary warning. Are there **any** other alternatives to solve this problem, though? Or are we stuck with "use `-p` and `-i` together, risky though that may be"?

Comment: In general, rebasing merges is going to be risky; that's just a consequence of how Git works. Rebase mostly tries to deal with linear history, and (non-fast-forward) merge mostly deals with non-linear history, hence why there are the rough edges when you try to combine the two. You might want to consider how important it is to you to edit the existing commit versus just creating a new commit with the fix.

Comment: Also note that "risky" here is relative - as long as you have the reflog enabled, you can always essentially hit "undo" on a rebase. So you can try it out and see if it works out properly, and if not, just use the reflog to find your old SHA and reset back to it.

Comment: Fantastic advice, thanks! I'm going to check out reflog in a minute. The points on "rebase in general being somewhat risky" are well taken. Like you said, "just do it" with `-p -i` it sounds like, and keep our finger over the shiny git undo button you've just told us about, just in case of funkyness. Great stuff!

Comment: On "you might want to just create a new commit/new branch with the corrections there": That's certainly an option to consider. For example. I thought of going back to the earliest "good" commit, & starting a new branch called "theGoodBranch". Then I could cherry-pick the commits from old "theBadBranch" one at a time, and SKIP the commit I'd wanted to delete. The problem? I've heard bad things about cherry-pick. [This page](http://dan.bravender.us/2011/10/20/Why_cherry-picking_should_not_be_part_of_a_normal_git_workflow.html) for example. I don't know an alternative to cherry-pick though

Comment: @Bukov cherry-picking is fine *if* you discard whatever branch you were cherry-picking *from* once you're done (this is basically what `rebase` does - it cherry picks each of the commits in order from the old branch, and then throws the old branch away, replacing it with the new version). The problems with cherry picks arise if you don't throw the old branch away, so you have versions of the change in both your old and new branches that have different SHAs.

Answer (score 1):

The above using `-p` and `-i` together is correct - however I wanted to point out that you dont *need* to use interactive more to get rid of a commit. You can use the `--onto` instead to explicitly state where you want your base to be. Assuming you want to get rid of HEAD~10,...

```
git rebase --onto HEAD~11 HEAD~9 HEAD
```

This says, take any commits that **are** in `HEAD`, but **are not* in `HEAD~9`, and apply them to the end of `HEAD~11`. That would mean it skips `HEAD~10`. The solution above works just fine, but sometimes, for getting rid of larger swaths of history, you may want to use `--onto`. Keep in mind that as is the case with `-p`, you can also use interactive mode with `--onto`.

With regard to [non-fast-forward merges and rebasing, take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973964/git-what-is-the-correct-merging-or-rebasing-workflow-to-modify-a-maintenance-br/16022472#16022472) answer I gave to another question. It mostly explains the use of `--onto`, but if you read through, you'll find an explanation regarding --no-ff merges and rebasing.